# download s3 bucket file using aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to download the file from s3-bucket using aws lambda function and upload the same file by renaming the file in another folder. In locally, I am able to download and upload the file But, i am not aware of aws lambda function about to download and upload. do we need to create any temp-folder in aws to download the file. Can anyone suggest me the bestway to download and upload the file..

Below is error what i am getting :

```
Response
 {
    "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    '/tmp/sample.csv'",
    "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
   "requestId": "5282a223-7b3a-42a9-9663-b1ab69388706",
  "stackTrace": [
 "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 34, in lambda_handler\n    
 with open(\"/tmp/sample.csv\", \"rb\") as f:\n"
 ]
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin, I will update the code with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions can only write to the `/tmp/` directory.

Make sure you download the file to that directory. For example:

```py
with open('/tmp/file`, "wb") as f:
```

You don't need to name this temporary file the same as the uploaded file, since you specify the S3 name via the `latest` variable.

Also, if the Lambda function context is reused, the next execution will overwrite the same file, which will prevent you from running out of space on the disk. A maximum of 512MB storage is provided.

Comment: I am getting the FilenotFound Error. When using   with open('/tmp/file_name.csv', "wb") as f:

Comment: I updated the code, what you suggested. But, I got the above error.

Comment: It's showing message like successfully downloaded.. but while uploading the file i am getting the error

Comment: Frankly, rather than using a `open()` and file handler, I would simply recommend using [`download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) and [`upload_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file). Give them a bucket, key and filename without having to use `with open(...) as f`.